# Doing telnet to unix server from command line and save output

Tags: unix, command-prompt

I am trying to use below command in command line

plink.exe -ssh lhostname -l username -pw password -m "c:\test.txt" > output.txt

But its returning only below content not the whole content

Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...

Connected to hostname (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

Escape character is '^]'.

Actual result should be as below :

Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...

Connected to hostname (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

Escape character is '^]'.

Connection closed by foreign host. (or telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Connection refused

```
                                telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused )
```

Is there any way I can get the complete output written to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Error message :

```
     telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Error message are redirected by `command-name 2> errors.txt`